# Issue with "pip install os-sys" on a mac 10.15

Tags: macos, pip

When I run the "pip install os-sys"

the following error comes up

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->os-sys) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->os-sys)

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/os-sys/

Under **Introduction** heading it contradicts the documentation and says to install via 'pip install os_sys' (an underscore as opposed to a hyphen)

Try that!

Comment: @FinnLawson hmmm, 'os_sys' works perfectly on my windows machine... try 'python3 -m pip install os_sys' or 'pip3 install os_sys'

Comment: im using mac 10.15  ill try that

Answer (score 0):

Your module seems to depend on `pywin32` which are extensions for python to access the win32 API. It is therefore Windows specific and does not work on MAC.

`os-sys` does therefore incorrectly state that it is os independent and can only be installed to a windows machine

Comment: so how would i use the "import sys" command or "sys.executable()"

Comment: @FinnLawson `sys` is built in in python, you don't need to install anything for that

Comment: {     finnlawson@Finns-MacBook-Pro pyblest % import sys
zsh: command not found: import      }

I'm always running into these errors when I try import some module into my terminal, I think i've set up my PYTHONPATH properly in my .bash_profile file, I'm unsure what this zsh shell really means (could be the issue)

Comment: You need to start a python interpreter to use these commands. Type `python` into your shell